# Override button click event from another form

Tags: vb.net, onclick, subroutine

Is there a way to override a forms button click event from a parent form?

For example, here's kind of what I have going on...

```
Dim newForm As New FormB
newForm.someproperty1 = True
newForm.someprpoerty2 = False

newForm.Show(Me)
```

I need to know what button was clicked when newForm is closed. I would normally use 'ShowDialog', but I can't since newForm needs to open up a DIFFERENT form that can't open as a Dialog... long story short, without a complete rewrite of our entire software, i can't use the ShowDialog.

Anyways, is there anyway that I can add button click events from another form? Something like...

```
Dim newForm As New FormB
newForm.btn1.click = SomeNewFunctionOrSubroutine()
newForm.btn2.click = SomeOtherFunctionOrSub()

newForm.Show(Me)
```

I've been looking at events and eventhandlers, but they aren't making too much sense...

Any tips?

Answer (score 3):

You could call AddHandler on your button in FormB (provided that its Modifier property is Public)

```
' This code is inside your Parent form
AddHandler newForm.btn1.click, AddressOf Me.SomeOtherFunctionOrSub


' This code is inside your Parent form
Protected Sub SomeOtherFunctionOrSub(sender as Object, e As EventArgs)
    ......
End Sub
```

Adding an Handler is a common practice to intercept the actions on a different form (For example, you probably will need also to intercept the Form.Closing event in case you want to have just one instance of newForm open at any time.)
An other approach (more complex) is subscribing to a custom event and requires the cooperation of FormB code. But in this scenario it doesn't seem to be necessary.

Comment: I seriously could hug you, you magnificent bastard.